# Properties of laplace type transform of $t^{\alpha - 1}$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, laplace-transform

Let $p>2, \frac{1}{p} < \alpha < 1- \frac{1}{p}$ and define $g_\alpha(t) := t^{\alpha - 1} \chi_{[1, \infty]}$. Then $g_\alpha \in L^p(\mathbb R)$. Define $$f(z) := \int_1^\infty g_\alpha(t) \exp(-izt) \, dt.$$
for $z\in \mathbb C, \operatorname{Im }z <0.$ Then:

> $a)$ $f$ is holomorphic in the lower half plane,
>   $b)$ The limit $$f_0(x):= \lim_{\substack{y\to 0 \\ y < 0}} f(x+iy)$$ exists for all $x\neq 0$,
>   $c)$ $f(z)$ does not satisfy an estimate of the form $$\forall \epsilon >0: \quad \lvert f(z) \rvert \leq C_\epsilon \exp((1+\epsilon)\lvert z \rvert),$$
>   $d)$ $f_0$ is not $p$-integrable in any neighbourhood of $0$.

I managed to show $a)$ using Lebesgue's theorem on interchanging derivative and integral sign. However, I am unsure with the other assertions, especially $c)$ and $d)$: How does one estimate the integral from below? And how I can I show something about $f_0 $ if I don't explicitly know it? Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we prove that
$$\tag{1}f(z) := \int_1^\infty t^{\alpha-1} e^{-izt} \, \mathrm{d} t$$
is convergent (as an improper Riemann integral) for all $z = x-iy$ with $x \ne 0$ and $y >0$. More presioulsy, the convergence is uniform if $|x| \ge x_0$ for fixed $x_0>0$. Thus (1) defines a continuous function and we have for $x \ne 0$ that
$$\tag{2}f_0(x) = \int_1^\infty t^{\alpha-1} e^{-ixt} \, \mathrm{d} t$$
**Prove:** For any $z= x-iy$ with $|x| \ge x_0$ and $y \ne 0$ we have with $1 \le a < b$ that
\begin{align}
\tag{3}\int_a^b t^{\alpha-1} e^{-izt} dt = \frac{1}{iz} ( a^{\alpha-1} e^{-iza} -  b^{\alpha-1} e^{-izb}) - \frac{\alpha-1}{iz} \int_a^b t^{\alpha-2} e^{-izt} dt.
\end{align}
The last line can be bounded by
$$\frac{1}{x_0} (a^{\alpha-1} + b^{\alpha-1}) +\frac{1-\alpha}{x_0} \int_a^b t^{\alpha-2} dt \le \frac{2}{x_0} a^{\alpha-1} $$
and thus (3) is a Cauchy sequence and thus convergent. In fact, it is (uniformly) convergent and thus continuous. (The whole argument is also known as *Dirchlet's test*, see for example [here](http://www.math.mcgill.ca/labute/courses/255w03/L23.pdf).)

**Prove of (c) and (d):** So we have shown (b). With the help of the explicit identity (2) we can also verify (c) and (d). In fact, we have (after coordinate of change) the identity
$$f_0(x) = x^{-\alpha} \int_x^\infty s^{\alpha-1} e^{-is} \, \mathrm{d} s.$$
Since the integrand is locally integrable (also in $s=0$) the function
$$g(x) := \int_x^\infty s^{\alpha-1} e^{-is} \, \mathrm{d} s$$
is continuous in $x=0$ with
$$\tag{4}g(0) = \int_0^\infty s^{\alpha-1} e^{-is} \, \mathrm{d} s.$$
Thus, it remains to show that $g(0) \ne 0$. Here we use the integral representation of (4). In fact, (4) is related to the Gamma function. One representation of the Gamma function (which was proven by Euler by using a contour shift argument) is
$$\Gamma(w) = e^{i \pi w /2} \int_0^\infty s^{w-1} e^{-is} \, \mathrm{d} s$$
if $0 < \mathrm{Re}(w) < 1$. Hence
$$g(0) = e^{-i \alpha \pi/2} \Gamma(\alpha) \neq 0.$$
All in all, we see that
$$\tag{5} f_0(x) \sim_\alpha x^{-\alpha} \quad (\text{for} \ x \rightarrow 0) $$
up to an non-zero constant (depending on $\alpha$).

c) can not hold, because c) would imply that $f_0$ is bounded. (5) implies that $f_0$ is not $p$-integrable (note that $\alpha p >1$) in any neighbourhood of $0$.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time! What do you mean by "$(3)$ is a Cauchy sequence"? In which way do you interpret this as a sequence?

Comment: Never mind, I got it. Thanks!

Comment: More precisely, I should say 'Cauchy-net'. There is a generalization of sequences called nets, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_(mathematics)). The bound shows that (3) can be made arbitary small if $a$ is large enough and that is exactly the property to be a Cauchy-net.

Comment: I see. But I also could just take a sequence, right?

Comment: Yes, you can take sequences, but not only one sequence. (If $\int_0^{x_n} g(t) \, dt$ is convergent with $x_n \rightarrow \infty$, then not necessarily this $\int_0^x g(t) dt$ is convergent.)

Comment: Sure :) I would just take an arbitrary sequence going to $+\infty$ not having to mess around with nets. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Sorry, but another question just came up: Is it not possible to handle your claims with Lebesgue theory? The integral is well defined as a Lebesgue integral too, isn't it?

Comment: No, for $y=0$ the integral is not absolute convergent, because $t^{\alpha-1}$ is not in $L^1([1,\infty)$. For $y >0$ it is not a problem, but we would like to determine the integral for $y=0$ and also see that it is continuous in $y$ in order to determine the limes.

Comment: True, I only thought about the $y<0 $ case...

Comment: Could you give a reference for the Dirichlet test you used? Your help is appreciated! :)

Comment: Yes, see my edited answer: The 'Dirichlet's test' is more or less the whole argument. We prove that the sequence is Cauchy and thus convergent, because $\mathbb{R}$ is complete.